# React native Svg icon calendar with date inside it

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

The result I want to get is:

[image]

The result that I created, an icon with the writing inside:

[image]

The icon was created using an SVG, as can be seen from the code below.

But the result I obtained does not satisfy me, I cannot get the result I had proposed considering the first image, the problems are the following.

1) Rounded corners in the part of the icon, the gray area.

I don't know how I can do this using svg.

Considering that the size can vary and the gray part must be similar to the image proposed.

2) Central the text of the date considering that the size of the icon can change.

Some advice?

Link: [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/HJSDBopPV)

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, Svg } from 'expo';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

var size = 30; //300

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to
          get a shareable url.
        </Text>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="calendar-blank" size={30} color="#000" />
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Svg height={size} width={size}>
            <Svg.Rect x={0} y={0} width={size} height={size} fill="#000" />
            <Svg.Rect
              x={size / 12}
              y={size / 6}
              width={size - size / 6}
              height={size - 6.5}
              fill="#fff"
            />
            <Svg.Text fontSize={size / 2} x={size / 4} y={size / 1.5}>
              21
            </Svg.Text>
          </Svg>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="calendar-blank"
            size={30}
            color="#000"
          />
        </View>

        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to
          get a shareable url.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    //alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea is a little bit different: to have one wrapper (a `View` component) and to use the calendar icon as a "background image" of it. Then position the dynamic date number in the middle of this wrapper:

```
<View style={styles.calendar}>
     <MaterialCommunityIcons name="calendar-blank" size={30} color="#000" style={styles.calendarIcon} />
     <Text style={styles.date}>21</Text>
</View>
```

Styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  calendar: {
    position: 'relative',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 30,
    height: 30, 
  },
  calendarIcon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0
  },
  date: {
    fontSize: 9,
    marginTop: 4
  }
});
```

Here is a working [example](https://snack.expo.io/SJ9N6QCPN).

Comment: Actually I wanted to try to make it using svg, but the solution is fine. I did the following test: https://snack.expo.io/Hynw_BRwE and I like the result.

Comment: @Paul, it looks nice :)